# Cypher: preventing results from duplicating on WITH / sequential querying

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In a query like this

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE id(a) = {x}

MATCH (a)-->(b:x)

WITH a, collect(DISTINCT id(b)) AS Bs

MATCH (a)-->(c:y)

RETURN collect(c) + Bs
```

what I'm trying to do is to gather two sets of nodes that came from different queries, but with this kind of procedure all the `b` rows get to be returned multiplied by the number of `a` rows.

How should I deal with this kind of problem that arises from sequential queries?

[Note that the reported query is only a conceptual representation of what I mean. Please don't try to solve the code (that would be trivial) but only the presented problem.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query shouldn't return any cross product since you aggregate in the `WITH` clause, so there is only one result item/row (the disconnected path `a, collect(b)`) when the second match begins. It's not clear therefore what the problem is that you want solved–cross products can be solved differently in different cases.

The way your query would work, conceptually speaking, is: match anything related from `a`, then filter that anything on having label `:x`. The second leg of the query does the same but filters on label `:y`. You can therefore combine your queries as

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
WHERE id(a) = {x} AND (b:x OR b:y)
RETURN b
```

Other cases of 'path explosion' can't be solved as easily (sometimes `UNION` is good, sometimes you can reorder your pattern, sometimes you can do some aggregate-and-reduce to make it happen) , but you'll have to ask about that separately.

Comment: does this produce different results than `MATCH (a)-->(b:x|y)` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using UNION for this?  See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-union.html#union-combine-two-queries-and-remove-duplicates

-brian